# Java: select object when parameter is given

Tags: java, class, object, bluej

I'm a beginning Java-programmer

Now I have this problem:
I have a class named `Producttype` with a field named `name`.
I also have a class called `Main`. Now in the class `Main` I want to select an object from the class `Producttype` by asking the name.

How can I do this?

Thanks in advance

code of Producttype:

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Producttype
{
    //velden
    private String naam;
    private String beschrijving;
    private double aankoopprijs;
    private double verkoopprijs;
    private int aantalGekocht;
    private int aantalVerkocht;

    //constructor
    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public Producttype(String naam, String beschrijving, double aankoopprijs, double verkoopprijs){
        this.naam = naam;
        this.beschrijving = beschrijving;
        this.aankoopprijs = aankoopprijs;
        this.verkoopprijs = verkoopprijs;
        aantalGekocht = 0;
        aantalVerkocht = 0;
    }
   public void drukInfo(){
        System.out.println("-----------------------");
        System.out.println("Naam van het product: " + naam);
        System.out.println("Beschrijving van het product: " + beschrijving);
        System.out.println("Aankoopprijs: " + aankoopprijs + " euro");
        System.out.println("Verkoopprijs: " + verkoopprijs + " euro");
        System.out.println("Aantal gekocht: " + aantalGekocht + " stuks");
        System.out.println("Aantal verkocht: " + aantalVerkocht + " stuks");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Aantal stuks in stock: " + berekenAantalInStock());
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Omzet momenteel: " + berekenOmzet() + " euro");
        System.out.println("Winst momenteel: " + berekenWinst() + " euro");
    }
```

In my 'Main' I got this:

```
private void printInfoOverProducttype()
    {
        String type = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Give the name of the producctype you want info of.");

        String info = ??????????????????????????

        System.out.println(info);
    }
```

What I want is that "String info" in the method printInforOverProducctype() is executes the method drukInfo() from the class 'Producctype' from the object where the name equals string type

Comment: Please post source code of Main/Producttype classes.

Comment: You may need to tell us more as your question seems incomplete and unaswerable to me. Do you have an array or collection such as an ArrayList of ProductType objects, and are you trying to select one whose name matches a particular String?

Comment: Just read a book for Java beginners, or any tutorial on Java from the beginning.

Comment: It appears you want to treat a Java program as accessing a database.  Java doesn't work this way. If you want to create an object, you create it and if you want to lookup a collection you select it by key or index.

Answer (score 2):

Your `Main` class needs to be able to access a `Map` of `ProductType` where the key is the name `String`:

```
public class Main {
    private Map<String, ProductType> products = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, ProductType>();

    public ProductType findProductTypeByName(String name) {
        return this.products.get(name);
    }
}
```